# How to show that $f(z)=\log(x^2+y^2)+iv(x,y)$ is not analytic in $U=\{z \in \mathbb{C}\colon 1<|z|<2 \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I think $f$ is analytic, because you can define that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v }{\partial y})+\frac{i}{2}(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{\partial v }{\partial y})+\frac{i}{2}(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}) = f'(z)$ $\forall z \in U$. So $f$ is analytic at U.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Your assumption that we are psychic is not valid; we have no idea what $v(x,y)$ is. But it can never be analytic for any $v(x,y)$.

Comment: $v(x,y)$ is harmonic($\Delta v =0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy-Riemann Equations:  A function is analytic if and only if $\frac{d}{d\overline{z}} = 0$.
$\frac{d}{d\overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{d}{dx} + \imath \frac{d}{dy})$

$\frac{d}{d \overline{z}} f(z) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} + \imath \frac{dv}{dx} + \imath (\frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} + \imath \frac{dv}{dy}))$

This implies that $\frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{dv}{dy}$ and that $\frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} = -\frac{dv}{dx}$.

Integrating both equations, we find that $v = 2 \arctan(y/x) + C(x)$ and that $v = -2 \arctan(x/y) + D(y)$.  It is easy to see that $C(x) = D(y) = c$, some constant..  So $v = 2 \arctan(\frac{x}{y}) = -2 \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$, an impossibility.